# Calculate distance considering road network using matlab

Tags: matlab, distance

I would like to calculate the distance between two coordinates using Matlab. However, this distance I would like to consider the road network. I wouldn't want to use any google API ok. The latitude and longitude of the two points are below:

% Coordinates of the points:

```
lat1 = -22.8851078223344;
lon1 = -48.4939312250395;
lat2 = -22.8315940282463;
lon2 = -48.4298167144681;
```

Comment: 1st you need to get a map, I suggest you download Google maps, the offline version. 2nd now comes the heavy part: you have import this map and write code to read road coordinates. If you manage to acquire a map in such manner, then it should be easy to key in LAT1 LON1 LAT2 LON2 and go from P1 to P2 on the shortest road, or even offer an alternative route.

Comment: The answer that Chunru gave you in the Mathworks forum is useless: If you had to only get an arch length it would be highly inprobable that there wouldn't be any need to ask, right?